# Topology: continuity on product of (metric) spaces

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces, product-space

What are the conditions so that the function defined on the product space $X\times Y$

$f: X \times Y\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ is continuous. For example, is there a condition that says that if any restriction on $X \times\{y_0\}$ or $\{x_0\}\times Y $ is continuous, then $f$ is continuous? Are there other conditions if we deal with metric spaces ?

Comment: Part of the def'n of a Topological Group $G$ is that $f:G\times G\to G$, where $f(a,b)=ab$, is continuous. I have an example of a group where  $f(a,b)=ab$ is continuous in each variable but $ f$ is not continuous....If a topological group is a $T_0$ space then it is a $T_n$ space for $n\leq 3\frac {1}{2}.$...  My example (which is NOT a Top'l Group although it is a topology ON a group),    is $ T_1$  but not  $ T_2$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such a simple condition as that. Consider the map$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\mathbb{R}^2&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&(x,y)&\mapsto&\begin{cases}\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}&\text{ if }(x,y)\neq(0,0)\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{array}$$Then $f$ is discontinuous, but each map $x\mapsto f(x,y_0)$ and $y\mapsto f(x_0,y)$ is continuous.

Comment: Even the partial derivatives exist everywhere, but $f$ is still discontinuous at $(0,0).$............+1